# slideToggle or any jquery animations not working when selecting certain elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When selecting elements out of the page like this:

```
$('.offers')[count - 1].slideToggle(500);
```

The slideToggle stops working along with any other animations however this does work:

```
$('.offers')[count - 1].style.display = 'block';
```

So the elements are being pulled out correctly but the jQuery animations are not working on them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are converting the jQuery object to a DOM Element object, you can use [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method instead:

```
$('.offers').eq(count-1).slideToggle(500);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.offers')[count - 1]
```

This will not return a jQuery object, but just the HTML element. You'll need to wrap this inside a jQuery object again, like this:

```
$($('.offers')[count - 1]).slideToggle(500);
```